# Do you need to release an @property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Do you need to `@property (nonatomic, assign) int variable;` in the .m file? If not, is there a reason why you don't need to release it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a good reason not to release it - it's not an object. And you should use @synthesize in your implementation (.m), and @property in your interface (.h).

Apple's [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) is a great place to find answers to questions like this.

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate on this? Why is it that you have to release all objects from memory but not `int`s?

Comment: Check the link - it goes into a *lot* more detail.

Comment: int's do not inherit NSObject, that is the reason.

Comment: @cfarm54: You need to learn about value types and objects. As a rule of thumb, if it's a pointer (has a star, as in `NSString *`) then it's most likely an object (when using pure Objective-C) and needs to be retained/released. If it doesn't, like with `int`, `NSInteger`, `NSRect/CGRect`, etc. then it's a value type and can't be released.

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand that you dont have to release primitive types, but the question is why not.

Comment: Like I said - the link I added explains the details.

Comment: cfarm54: Value types store their value in the variable itself. References types store a pointer to their value. In the case of Objective-C, all instances are stored in the heap and must be `release`d when no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release only those variable that you allocated or used.